# How do you resume a paused Step Function state machine?

Tags: aws-step-functions

I have seen some slideshow about how one can resume a paused step functions state machine using a token. I looked through the API docs to figure out how to do this myself but could not. How exactly is the token used to find the paused state machine and which API is used to continue it?

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing I can think of is activity (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-activities.html) however that requires creating a worker. Activity token which is then received (`GetActivityTask`) can be used to resume state machine later (`SendTaskSuccess` or `SendTaskFailure`).

However I can think of a way to solve this without using additional worker (so you wouldn't need to create some always-working task): create parallel state which has two tasks:

1. Activity task which will be used to pause state machine
2. Task with lambda function which pulls for token from `GetActivityTask` and sends it somewhere (for example - start external process which will later resume state machine)

State machine would look like this:

[image]

`WaitForResume` would be task with activity and `PullToken` would call `GetActivityTask`. Keep in mind however that inside `PullToken` you can get token for any execution of that state machine, not the actual execution. `PullToken` should also have configured retry policy to solve potential issues with race conditions. Note that this is only optimization to reduce costs - straightforward way is to have additional activity worker.

Comment: What I am looking for is there a way I can pause the state machine without defining any additional state or task. Because I want to pause the state machine based on some external event(which can happen anytime without prior information). As per my needs, my state machine is always running  and so if any external event occurs, I want to then pause the state machine for certain amount of time

Comment: In case you haven't figured it out by now, there is a `WAIT` state you can use: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-wait-state.html.